# Multiple AJAX functions on one functions page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'd like to find a way of having a single page in the root of each of my web sections to hold all of the databae queries I'm calling.

I'm using a little script .....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
     var availableTags = <?php include('fn-search-em.php'); ?>;
     $("#quick-add").autocomplete({
         source: availableTags,
            autoFocus:true
     });
     });
</script>
```

.... to do SQL searches that appear as the user is typing.  Similar to this ....

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock_c_colours WHERE current_c_status = 'current' AND deleted = 'no'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$results_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $colour_id = $row['id'];
    $range_name = $row['range_name'];
    $range_colour = $row['colour'];
    $colour_code = $row['code'];
    $p1 = $row['piece_size_1'];
    $p2 = $row['piece_size_2'];

    if($p1 > 1){
        $p_mark = 'x';
    }
    else {
        $p_mark = '';
    }

     $results_list[] = $range_name.' ('.$range_colour.' '.$colour_code.' '.$p1.$p_mark.$p2.') ID:'.$colour_id;
}
echo json_encode($results_list);
```

Echos a list in the form of a JSON array back to the text box and voila, a list.  However, the site I'm working on at the moment has about 20 search boxes for various reasons scattered around (user request), does this mean I have to have 20 separate php function pages, each with their own query on, or can a single page be used?

I suspect the java needs modifying a little to call a specific function on a page of multiple queries, but I'm not good with Java, so some help would be greatly appreciated.

I did initially try adding ?action= to the end of the PHP address in the Java script, hoping a GET on the other end would be able to separate the PHP end into sections, but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `<?php include('fn-search-em.php'); ?>;` to `<?php $action = 'mode1'; include('fn-search-em.php'); ?>;`.

Then in your `fn-search-em.php` file, use the `$action` variable to determine what kind of MySQL query you make.

For example:

```
if ($action == 'mode1') 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stock_c_colours WHERE current_c_status = 'current' AND deleted = 'no'";
else
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stock_c_colours WHERE current_c_status = 'mode1' AND deleted = 'no'";
```

Comment: Thank you.  Chose this answer due to sheer simplicity and minimal modification to current code.  I really need to get up to speed with some basic Java:(

Comment: This is probably a really dumb question, but would I be better off (as they are only tiny SQL queries, just putting the whole of the query into the availableTags variable?  Then I could do away with the sep PHP page all together and just write the queries adhoc as I need to.

Comment: Hey Stephen, you definitely do not want to include an SQL query directly into your JavaScript code as this will open up your code to anyone executing whatever SQL query one pleases without your authorization. You must make sure that your SQL query is getting generated server-side and that any string values accepted and included into your SQL query (that come from the client-side via JavaScript) get escaped using the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with by creating a php file with a switch statement to control what code is executed during your Ajax call:

JS:

```
$.ajax({url: 'ajax.php', method: 'POST', async:true, data: 'ari=1&'+formData,complete: function(xhr){ var availableTags = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);}});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    switch($_REQUEST['ari']){
        case 1:
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM stock_c_colours WHERE current_c_status = 'current' AND deleted = 'no'";
           $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

           $results_list = array();
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $colour_id = $row['id'];
            $range_name = $row['range_name'];
            $range_colour = $row['colour'];
            $colour_code = $row['code'];
            $p1 = $row['piece_size_1'];
            $p2 = $row['piece_size_2'];

            if($p1 > 1){$p_mark = 'x';}
            else { $p_mark = ''; }
            $results_list[] = $range_name.' ('.$range_colour.' '.$colour_code.' '.$p1.$p_mark.$p2.') ID:'.$colour_id;
           }
           echo json_encode($results_list);
        break;
        case 2:
            // another SQL Query can go here and will only get run if ARI == 2
        break;
    }
?>
```

This allows you to keep multiple AJAX handlers in the same file, you just need to pass the index for the desired handler when you make calls to the PHP file or nothing will happen.