# Client Side Value - set variable

Tags: php, html

A user enters my site and a third party application generates an html value client side. The value is not set by my code but by the application; how can I set this value as a variable?

An example as I struggle to explain:
User A visits site, my application is executed and the user sees the number "1" in plaintext. The goal is to place set the number as a variable in php to be used later.

Comment: You would need to use some JavaScript to send the value to php asynchronously (AJAX). You can't set values in PHP after the page loads. I recommend jquery for this kind of thing as it simplifies a lot of the leg work

Comment: Do you have any recommended strings? I assume I have to wait until the page loads of course.

Comment: Well it depends a lot on how the third part app defines the variable. Essentially you would need to wait until that is complete then use JavaScript to send the value to a php script which could store/use it as needed. There are a lot of other answers about the basics of doing this with the jQuery $.ajax() function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35660716/5641249 I wrote this one about using one php script to handle multiple ajax requests

Comment: You could use sessions or cookies